# I'm trying to create a horizontal week view calendar with infinite scroll in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I want to create a horizontal week view calendar that will be infinite scrollable.
I was able to achieve it but the transition to next month is smooth where in the transition to previous month is instant and displays the 1st day of the previous month.

Please check the [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0n80ox)

Note: I don't want to use any package / third party library.

PS: I tried finding the solution but couldn't

Comment: Please include your code (or a link) and give more details.

Comment: I've already attached the Code sandbox link, pasting link again https://codesandbox.io/s/0n80ox

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines in your function handleHorizontalScroll:

```
  const newDays= ((new Date(dateRange[0])).getTime() - date.getTime())/3600/24/1000;
  e.scrollTo(newDays * currentDayRef.current.clientWidth,0)
```

the function become:

```
  const handleHorizontalScroll = () => {
    let e = document.getElementById("week-view-wrapper");
    if (Math.ceil(e.scrollLeft) + e.clientWidth >= e.scrollWidth) {
      console.log("reached Right");
      let date = new Date(dateRange[1]);
      let y = date.getFullYear(),
        m = date.getMonth();
      let lastDay = formatDates(new Date(y, m + 2, 0), "yyyy-mm-dd");
      console.log("lastDay", dateRange[1], lastDay, m, [dateRange[0], lastDay]);
      setDateRange([dateRange[0], lastDay]);
    } else if (e.scrollLeft <= 0) {
      console.log("reached Left");
      let date = new Date(dateRange[0]);
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
      let y = date.getFullYear(),
        m = date.getMonth();
      let firstDay = formatDates(new Date(y, m, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd");
      console.log("firstDay", firstDay);
      console.log("scrollWidth", e.scrollWidth, e.clientWidth);
      const newDays= ((new Date(dateRange[0])).getTime() - date.getTime())/3600/24/1000;
      e.scrollTo(newDays * currentDayRef.current.clientWidth,0)      
      setDateRange([firstDay, dateRange[1]]);
      // parentRef.current?.scrollTo(e.scrollWidth, 0);
    }
  };
```

Maybe there are still improvement can be done. Foe example, you can pass some paramter to a Ref and then call e.scrollTo in a useEffect().

Please find the sandbox link [below:https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontal-infinite-scroll-wip-forked-xfxhgz?file=/src/week.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontal-infinite-scroll-wip-forked-xfxhgz?file=/src/week.js)